# In Rails 4, is there a way to override the to_s method to display a url field correctly?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My `Profile` model has a `portfolio_url` field.

In error messages (as well as other places), it's displayed as 'Portfolio Url'.

Is there a way to customize this in one place (my guess is overriding a `to_s` method) so it's displayed as `Portfolio URL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to override a method to change the label of an `ActiveRecord` attribute. Just add the name you want to use to your translation file:

```
# in config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      profile:
        portfolio_url: "Portfolio URL"
```

Read more about [`ActiveRecord` translations in the Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models).